# Need help for looping through JSON, resulting by an API that have different structures for different request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to retrieve the first "dt"  from the first "entry" from a JSON result that send by an API, unfortunatelly , It have different structures for different request,

The JSON codes generating is too long to paste here, so I'm giving the direct API url

The API URL : http://codename47.hostei.com/?word=medical_word

Try some medical words instead of the "medical_word" in the URL, will result different structured JSON for different request ..

for eg : if word=eye generate one structure and 
 word=blood will result another structure ,

I just want to retrieve the first "dt" 's value from every JSON .
How can I achieve that , How will be the JavaScript code..

In the Index HTML the JSON respond will store in a object named result

var result=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to be fast, I'm at work... it think this should work but a framework for that must exists.

```
function findDt(obj){
    if( typeof obj !== "object"){
        return;
    }
    var res =null;

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).some( function (prop) {
        if(prop === "dt") {
            res = obj["dt"];
            return res;
        }
        res = findDt( obj[prop] );
        return res;
    });
    return res;
}
```

Comment: It worked greatly bro, this is my 3rd post about this Problem in SO

Comment: Once more time , THANKS< but i want to know ehat this Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).some() will do here, can you give me little word about that..

Comment: I'm not a JS developper so there is certainly another solution. Object.getOwnPropertyNames will give you the "keys" of the arg object (not the ones from prototype chaining but there is no such chain in JS). Some will do the callback function until one returns a valid result. Yeah it's not perfect but again, I'm Java dev, not JS :p

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some